# How to format time() string to Unix Timestamp in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I stored `time()` string in to my database like `1363694642`
Now i just want to print this sting Like `19-03-2013 17:40:39`

I already used `date('d-M-Y H:i:s', strtotime($row['time']))` but it return `31-Dec-1969 17:00:00` in every query

Kindly help me to resolve it.

Comment: You are mistaken... A time value like `1363694642` produced by the `time()` function **is** an epoch (unix) timestamp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`date` function requires a timestamp, so you don't have to use `strtotime`, because you already has a timestamp from database:

```
date('d-m-Y H:i:s', $row['time'])
```

Notice, that I've replaced `M` with `m` in your format string. That's because `M` means *A short textual representation of a month, three letters* and you want just a number.

Comment: Thanks a lot and i just manipulated here DEC with 19-**12**-2013

Answer (score 0):

just use this

```
date('d-M-Y H:i:s', $row['time']);
```

Answer (score 0):

you will not need to use the strtotime function as the time() return the timestamp value itself:

Use: `date('d-m-Y H:i:s', $row['time'])`

for more go through http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: How does this answer differ to mine? :)

Comment: @ MarcinJuraszek: Sorry I didnt noticed that you have already posted the same.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL can already do this for you:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(`time`)
FROM ...
```

Or:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(`time`, '%D-%M-%Y %h:%i:%s')
FROM ...
```

See also: [`FROM_UNIXTIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)